# Which sql join should I use here to combine all the rows?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Table 1 :

```
X , Y , Z 
10, 12, 14
20, 17, 18
```

Table  2:

```
X ,  Y, Z
100, 75, 80
375, 100, 122
```

I have 7 such tables. Expected outcome is combining only all rows. Which Join should I use?

Final Table

```
X , Y , Z 
10, 12, 14
20, 17, 18
100, 75, 80
375, 100, 122
```

Comment: Seeing the above tables, you don't need any join rather just use `UNION ALL` @AnupBuchke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you need is to *union* together the result of each query:

```
Select X, Y, Z
from t1
union all
Select X, Y, Z
from t2
union all.... ;
```

You can remove `all` if you need to exclude any duplicate rows, but if you don't keep `union all` as removing duplicates carries additional overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Check out SQL Union

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

This isn't technically a join on common data, rather a way to combine the results from tables with the same schema (column definitions)